# Unable to sort date field which is stored as value "Dtae(-62135596800000)" on MongoDB 3.4

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query

I'm using Robo 3T to fetch data from MongoDB 3.4.
I have one collection in which date time is stored as some numeric value like "-62135596800000". Collection:
   `{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a8eaf90e97a220a145dbf20"),
    "Receiver" : "test@test.com",
    "ReceiverName" : null,
    "Codes" : [],
    "Status" : 3,
    "Failurs" : 0,
    "Language" : 1,
    "Created" : Date(-62135596800000),
    "CouponId" : ObjectId("5a8eaf90e97a220a145dbf1e")
}`

I want to sort this colelction's data with Created descending.
I tried using query:

```
db.getCollection('Emails').find().sort({"Created": -1}).limit(10)
```

But it does not sort records based on `Created` key descending.
What am I missing here ?

Comment: Because `Date(-62135596800000)` makes no sense. If you check your collection, `Created` holds ISODate object with current date, not a "numeric value like -62135596800000"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's can't work because `Created` contains the Dates but this data are not properly stored. So first store proper data and then try it.  In additional you can add `timestamps: true` in your schema. It will store `ISODate()` when new record inserted.
  `{ collection: 'user', timestamps: true }`